# Loop in a bash script with adb command

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I'm beginning with bash ans I'm trying to loop in a shell script to pull different apk's from my android device.

I've got a file with apk's paths

## apkpaths.txt

> /data/app/com.naver.linewebtoon-1/base.apk
>
> /data/app/com.game5mobile.lineandwater-1/base.apk

I read this file and try to applicate this script but only the first apk is pulled but three times. How can I create a single file app.apk for each apk I pull with the adb command line ?

```
#!/bin/bash


filename="$1"
while IFS=: true; do
 line=''
 read -r line
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    break
  fi
  END=3
  for i in $(seq 1 $END);
    do adb shell cat $line > app$i.apk;
  done
   #echo "$line"
done < "$filename"
```

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest removing your for loop that is coded to loop 3x's. Let your while loop read every line from the file and than execute your adb command for each line/apk

Comment: use `adb pull` for binary files.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
fileNum=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    adb shell cat $line > app$fileNum.apk
    let "fileNum++"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Error : fileNum++: command not found

Comment: sorry it should be let "fileNum++"

Comment: That's what you wrote ? Indeed I have a "syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")"